# Get object from database with Angular

Tags: angular

I created my backlog with symfony, everything is ok, but now, I try to get my infos from the database.

My products will be owned by a category (which is an object), and I'm trying to display all my categories, but my TS request seems....bad.

Here is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let categorie of getAll()">{{ categorie }}</li>
</ul>
```

**Component:**

```
export class ShowCatComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() { }

    constructor(private categorieService: CategorieService) {

    }

    getAll() {
        let categories;
        categories = this.categorieService.getAllCategorie();
        console.log(categories);
        return categories;
    }


}
```

**service**

```
  getAllCategorie(): Promise<any> {
        const UserToken = this.localStorage.get('userToken');
        const jsonToken = JSON.parse(UserToken);
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                Authorization: jsonToken["token"]
            })
        };
        return this.http.get(this.HTTP_URL + this.GET_CATEGORIES_URL, httpOptions).toPromise()
            .then((response: Array<any>) => { return response.map(el => Categorie) });
    }
```

This last request seems the problem, here is the log:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Promise]'
> of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
> Arrays.

Comment: Have a look to the pipe async (`| async`)

Comment: Where should I consider it? :x

Comment: Here is a [link](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-async-pipe/) to learn how it works. You have an asynchronous call, you have to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `service.getAllCategorie()` returns a `Promise` but `ngFor` only allows to loop over iterables such as Arrays (as the error says). The easiest way to fix this would be (as user 'Random' correctly identified) to use the `async` pipe. Just change the `ngFor` to `let categorie of (getAll() | async)`. This way the Promise will be resolved first, before looping over the result.